# Mercurial Where are the Pulled Files

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I'm pretty new to mercurial, never used it before.

What I did:

I've created the main repository on one pc (lonnected through lan)
and created folders on other PC (personal repos) by cloning the main one.
After that I've created a test file, commited it and pushed to the main repo. The other pc did so as well. Then we polled those changes from the main repo and it seemed to work fine.

The question is - where are those files? How can I use them for my project, open with visual studio, for example? Where are those workable copies stored?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you `update` the working directory after pull?

Comment: have a look at http://hgbook.red-bean.com/ or https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MercurialBook

Comment: @user694733 Yeah, you were right. It did help. Totaly forgot about it.